# How do I change the font of a control in WinApi C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

How do I change the font of an edit control in win32 API.
I would like to be able to edit the style as well as the color of a font on a edit control.

Comment: You want to use `WM_SETFONT`. Also, 2 suggestions, 1) There is a ton of info on the net about using the winapi, if you would search for `edit control font winapi` in your favorite search engine, you should find a lot of info. 2) Ever hear of Charles Petzold? He has a very famous book explain a lot about the winapi, I recommend getting his book and learning from that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you should clarify that you're talking about a standard Edit control versus a Rich Edit control - the two are totally different.

You can change the font by sending a [`WM_SETFONT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642.aspx) message to the edit control. Setting the color is a totally different process.

You can set the text color by responding to the [`WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761691.aspx) message in the owner of the edit control.

Answer (score 4):

You can send it a [WM_SETFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#changing_fonts) message.  Be warned, though, as the link explains, you may have to re-size the control after changing the font.

Comment: @PotentVenom: Not without writing the code yourself (e.g intercepting the WM_SETFONT message and resizing based upon the incoming info).  What would you set it to a percentage of anyway?

Answer (score 1):

For a standard edit control, handle the `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` message to set the text and background colours.