# Changing the font size of a static textbox in a Windows GUI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

how do you change the font size of a static text box in a Windows GUI application written in C++?

```
HWND hText = CreateWindowW(L"EDIT", L"enter some text", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | ES_RIGHT, 100, 100, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

do i have to make another Window message

Comment: I've added the `winapi` and `windows` tags, as I assume that's your target API and platform? C++ doesn't have ny kind of "GUI" functionality, so you always need to tell us which API or framework you're using. And GUI's are often very target-platform specific so always add that as well. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Also please try to create a [mcve] of your own attempt and show it to us in the question, together with a description of the problems with it.

Comment: you need first create font by `CreateFont[Indirect]W` and then send [`WM_SETFONT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-setfont) message to control

Comment: I'm using Windows API, and yeah I should do some more reading. It's my first time asking a question here. Thank you RbMm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the font of a control in WinApi C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994992/how-do-i-change-the-font-of-a-control-in-winapi-c)

Answer (score 2):

As @RbMm said that, use `CreateFont` and `WM_SETFONT` can achieve this. And the official documents also have corresponding introduction.

[Changing the Font Used by an Edit Control.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/edit-controls-text-operations#changing-the-font-used-by-an-edit-control)

> An application can change the font that an edit control uses by
>   sending the [WM_SETFONT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-setfont) message. Most applications do this while
>   processing the [WM_INITDIALOG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/wm-initdialog) message. Changing the font does not
>   change the size of the edit control; applications that send the
>   **WM_SETFONT** message may have to retrieve the font metrics for the text and recalculate the size of the edit control. For more
>   information about fonts and font metrics, see [Fonts and Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/fonts-and-text).

The least code:

```
LOGFONT logfont; 
ZeroMemory(&logfont, sizeof(LOGFONT));
logfont.lfCharSet = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
logfont.lfHeight = -20; 
HFONT hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&logfont);

SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont, TRUE);
```

Comment: so I just need to declare a font class, define some attributes and then use that?

Comment: @raafiAbdul Yes, beacuse applications that send the WM_SETFONT message have to retrieve the font metrics for the text.